# If Zuul 2.0 in Spring Cloud?

Tags: websocket, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

In Github, artgon in Zuul said "we are planning to open source Websocket and SEE support in Zuul 2.0.". So Spring Cloud use the zuul 2.0? If not, is there other way to support the use in Spring Cloud when I use zuul?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Cloud is not going to integrate zuul 2.0 as it is not backwards compatible and they just announced a supported branch last week. We have created Spring Cloud Gateway that supports websockets and see. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/

Comment: sorry for replying too late.I will try this!It will be great if an demo can be provided.